# Duplicate LINQ to SQL entity / record?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

What would be considered the best practice in duplicating [cloning] a LINQ to SQL entity resulting in a new record in the database?

The context is that I wish to make a duplicate function for records in a grid of an admin. website and after trying a few things and the obvious, read data, alter ID=0, change name, `submitChanges()`, and hitting an exception, lol. I thought I might stop and ask an expert.

I wish to start with first reading the record, altering the name by prefixing with "Copy Of " and then saving as a new record.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new instance and then use the linq mapping classes together with reflection to copy member values.

E.g.

```
public static void CopyDataMembers(this DataContext dc,
                                   object sourceEntity,
                                   object targetEntity)
{
    //get entity members
    IEnumerable<MetaDataMember> dataMembers = 
         from mem in dc.Mapping.GetTable(sourceEntity.GetType())
                                 .RowType.DataMembers
         where mem.IsAssociation == false
         select mem;

    //go through the list of members and compare values
    foreach (MetaDataMember mem in dataMembers)
    {
       object originalValue = mem.StorageAccessor.GetBoxedValue(targetEntity);
       object newValue = mem.StorageAccessor.GetBoxedValue(sourceEntity);

        //check if the value has changed
        if (newValue == null && originalValue != null 
            || newValue != null && !newValue.Equals(originalValue))
        {
            //use reflection to update the target
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfo = 
                targetEntity.GetType().GetProperty(mem.Name);

            propInfo.SetValue(targetEntity, 
                              propInfo.GetValue(sourceEntity, null), 
                              null);

            // setboxedvalue bypasses change tracking - otherwise 
            // mem.StorageAccessor.SetBoxedValue(ref targetEntity, newValue);
            // could be used instead of reflection
        }
    }
}
```

...or you can clone it using the DataContractSerializer:

```
internal static T CloneEntity<T>(T originalEntity) where T : someentitybaseclass
{
    Type entityType = typeof(T);

    DataContractSerializer ser =
        new DataContractSerializer(entityType);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ser.WriteObject(ms, originalEntity);
        ms.Position = 0;
        return (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! This is working, I did contemplate reflection.  How do you feel about this solution? I suppose any built-in Clone() I was expecting would perform a similar operation..

Comment: If you have read-only properties in your entity you need to check if the property has a setter before calling propInfo.SetValue. You can do that my checking if propInfo.GetSetMethod() returns a non-null value.

Answer (score 13):

If you load entity from DataContext with set ObjectTrackingEnabled to false then you can insert this entity as new in another DataContext

```
DataContext db1 = new DataContext();
DataContext db2 = new DataContext();

db2.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

MyEntity entToClone = db2.Single(e => e.Id == id);

// ... change some data if it is needed

db1.MyEntities.InsertOnSubmit(entToClone);
db1.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I found that it also cloned child objects, something that I didn't want. I still think this is the best solution. Linq to SQL should have a built in elegant method for this.

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck with the same problem and Kristofer's code worked perfectly, many thanks!

In case someone is interested, I slightly modified his code so that instead of accepting the target entity as a parameter, it creates a new object and returns it. Also I have made the `sourceEntity` parameter to be generic:

```
 public static T CloneEntity<T>(this DataContext dc, T sourceEntity) where T:class, new()
 {
     var targetEntity = new T();
     //... original method code...
     return targetEntity;
 }
```

Then I can do the following:

```
dataContext.MyEntities.Attach(dataContext.CloneEntity(theEntity));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is he same solution as Peter K., for the Linq-to-Sql Entiry Clone in VB.Net.

```
    Dim DC As New DataContext
    Dim DCI As New DataContext
    DC.ObjectTrackingEnabled = False

        Dim RGF As sf_RuleGroup = (From G In DC.sf_RuleGroups _
                                  Where G.RuleGroupID = CInt(e.CommandArgument) _
                                  Select G).First()
        DCI.sf_RuleGroups.InsertOnSubmit(RGF)
        DCI.SubmitChanges()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Entity framework 6 you can do this

```
Dim WorkoutNew As New Workout 'create a record
ff7db.Workouts.Add(WorkoutNew) 'add it to the table (workout)
ff7db.Entry(WorkoutNew).CurrentValues.SetValues(WorkoutsPost) ' update its values with a class with the same properties
```