# Duplicate LINQ to SQL entity / record - with associated records?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq from ASP.NET (C#); and I'm trying to add a 'clone record' function. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637535/duplicate-linq-to-sql-entity-record) - allows copying of a single record from a single table; how can I expand it to include associated records in tables linked through foreign keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with CopyDataMembers, suggested elsewhere on this site, and then looped through each entry in each of the linked tables and copied them individually. Not ideal by far, but it meets the requirements and the deadline.